# Tool to launch non-portable software from external hard disk

Tags: portable

Is there any software what allows me to carry my own documents, software, register etc. on external hard disc?

I want to carry with me non-portable software. Normally, I just use some VM but it can't be used because it requires administrator(because of drivers). Something like Wine, fake computer environment where apps can be launched through environment's launcher. Something like this also allows me to install software even without administrator because I'll carry my own registry with me.

Does someone know about tool like this?

Target platform is Windows, and preferable open source. I have no budget for this, but if nothing else work i will pay for software. As person without bank account I can't use software paid pre month.

*ps. I know about partableapps.com but it won't allows me have my own registry so posibilites are very limited.*

Comment: Do you want to run the OS within a host OS, like Windows or Mac  or would it work to purely boot from the thumbdrive?  I think either are possible with Linux.

Comment: @djangofan Yeah, i tried linux but host computers supports only x32 besides fact than host computer is school computer and they boot from network disc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Enigma Virtual Box Free, Lightweight, perfect.

EDIT : Enigma Virtual Box has many downsides. I found [Cameyo Packager](https://www.cameyo.com/cameyo-offline/) what is more stable and have less antivirus false alerts. Unlike Enigma Virtual Box where you need to add everything manually, Cameyo Packager works on pre-scan and post-scan just like commercial packager. Same as Enigma Virtual Box, Cameyo Packager is aswell lightweight and simple and it comes in single executable and is fully portable (admin needed)

Answer (score 2):

- [VMWare Thinapp](https://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp.html) (formerly Thinstall) enables you to create your own portable applications, using a virtual registry. 
  I used it several years ago to package an Office 2007 installation, and it worked pretty well.
- [BoxedApp Packer](https://www.boxedapp.com/boxedapppacker/) seem to offer the same fucntionality, but I never digged into it.

Note that both are commercial products.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are several programs that can help you.
I like BoxedApp Packer. This is quite powerful tool. It is paid, but it is cheaper than the similar program - ThinApp.
Also, I know about such a program as FilePacker, but I have not tried this program.